# Setting max-sessions for User Roles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, I'd like to use different max-session for different USER ROLES. For example, "admin" role should be allowed to use 3 max-session and "user" role should be allowed to use just 1 max-session.

In spring-security.xml, it is possible to set, but for all users.
I am not able to achieve it role-wise. Is it possible to achieve it role wise?

spring-security.xml

```
...
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/" 
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </session-management>
</http>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED FROM M_AD_USERS WHERE USERNAME=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT USERNAME, ROLE FROM M_AD_USER_ROLES WHERE USERNAME=?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the beauty of the spring framework as it is highly configurable.

1. Configure a custom SessionManagementFilter and use it at POSITION of SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER.
2. Define a custom(overriden) ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy and maintain a map through configuration of max sessions through the configuration of this.
3. In the overriden onAuthentication() method of ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, use this map to validate and save user sessions based on role.

Hope this is clear.